# Tapping and longpressing in spanish?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

I make apps in my free time and I try to localize them myself, mostly using Google Translate, existing open source resource files etc.

Some words though, are very specific when it comes to computer or smart phone usage, so the translations I come up with can sometimes be totally out of context.

For example, how would you translate "tap", "long press", "swipe" and "flick"?
These are typical words that come up all the time in smart phone usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit difficult translate those words to spanish. I will translate it like:

> Tap: **Tocar**
>
> Long press: I've seen multiple ways to translate this word, like: "Pulsación larga", "pulsar prolongadamente", "mantener pulsado"... I personally like the first one.
>
> Swipe: **Deslizar** or **arrastrar**
>
> Flick: **Tocar** (Complete translation will be "Tocar rápidamente", but it's too long)

Comment: Thank you! I don't have the reputation to vote you up, but if I had, I would definitely do that! Thanks again!

Comment: Here is a complete sentence I'm trying to translate:
"Tap a name to make it your favorite. Long press a name to share it." "Toque en el nombre para agregarlo a tus favoritos. Pulsación larga un nombre para compartirla." Would you say that is correct?

Comment: I would say: "Toca un nombre para agregarlo a tus favoritos. Mantén pulsado un nombre para compartirlo.".
I put the noun of long press, not the verb, my fault. In my opinión, "mantener pulsado" (press and hold) or "pulsar prolongadamente" are the best approximations. The first one sounds more natural to me.

Comment: In my opinion, the translation of 'flick' is not very good. If I read 'tocar', I won't do the gesture depicted here (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/gestures-flick-pan-and-stretch) as 'flick'. However, I can't give a better translation :(